# link_to helper not rendering the correct URL for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hyperlink, link-to

I have a `Request` model. In one of my views, I'm trying to render a link to it.

The first thing I tried was the following:

```
.requests-container
  = link_to request, class: "request-link"
```

The following link renders as `<a href="/requests?class=request__title">My request 1</a>`. The `class` option gets mixed in the URL. That's understandable, though, since `link_to` seems to expect the URL as the second parameter.

---

After that, I tried this version:

```
.requests-container
  = link_to request
```

The result turned out to be even stranger, though, since the generated link was the following: `<a href="/requests">My request 1</a>`.

In this link, the `href` attribute is generated as **`/requests`** instead of **`/requests/2`**, the expected URL for this ActiveRecord object.

---

Even more strangely, my following attempt,

```
.requests-container
  = link_to request, request, class: "request-link"
```

yielded a fully working link: `<a class="request-link" href="/requests/2">My request 1</a>`. That is the expected link and it works fine.

---

Is this a known behaviour in Rails? There are other parts in my code where I've just used `link_to <activerecord object>` and it has worked fine, so I am not completely sure why it didn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

link_to takes first argument as `body` of the link which will be displayed on the view and second argument is the actual URL

When you tried

```
= link_to request, class: "request-link"
```

It took `class: "request-link"` as `params`

But in the second case you actually passed the `object` as the 2nd parameter, which is correct

```
= link_to request, request, class: "request-link"
```

Here the third parameter comes under `options` hash

If you take a look at the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) you will find this example

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
# url is a String; you can use URL helpers like
# posts_path
```

From the above example it's clear that the first, second and third arguments are `body`, `url` and `html_options` respectively.

Comment: You forgot to mention the usage of `link_to` with a block: `link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)` : If `&block.present?` it will use the block as the "stuff to display", if no block is given, it will use the first argument as the "stuff to display".

Comment: So basically I'm expected to pass `request` twice?

Comment: One of the proper way to use the `link_to` in your case would be `link_to 'stuff to display', request, class: 'request-link'` (generates `<a class="request-link" href="/requests/2">stuff to display</a>`)

Comment: No you are not sending it twice, take a look at this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: @MrYoshiji in the above example block has not been used that's why the first argument is body